# Parameter Validation for AWS Api Gateway

Tags: validation, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

So I created a resource and a GET action on my Api Gateway. I correctly pass my url parameters through Method Execution and through Integration Request via Mapping Templates. Currently I am having my Api endpoint execute a Lambda function when hit and there are parameter validates in my Lambda function. I was hoping there would be a way for Api Gateway to tell me validate the url parameters for me. But I can't find any documentation or blog that teaches me how to do that. I heard in a previous post that this feature may come in later if people complain to AWS enough, but that was like last year.

Comment: Is the feature request I describe below what you had in mind? Or did you envision a more powerful validation mechanism?

Comment: Yes sorry about that, that did answer my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is still on our backlog, we don't yet validate incoming parameters.

The feature request we have to is just validating that they are present. Basically you would say a parameter is required and then if the parameter was missing, API Gateway would reject the request before it reached the Lambda function.

Comment: May I know whether this validation implemented or still in backlog?

Comment: @bravokeyl the good news is that yes, this has been implemented http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-method-request-validation.html (also, see blog post here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/how-to-remove-boilerplate-validation-logic-in-your-rest-apis-with-amazon-api-gateway-request-validation/)

Comment: @eyko Thanks for the link, I already checked it but don't think it's the same for the same for the request path just like request body. I tried to use pattern in the request path but it seems to be not working. Here is full my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47194894/2007486)