# Validating request path parameter of AWS API gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, swagger-2.0

Let's say I have an api with paths `/` and `/{pets}` and `/{pets}/pet`. Now I'm trying to validate the path `{pets}` parameter so that only path having alphanumerical characters of length 6 will be validated and processed to the backend lambda all others will be rejected. I tried the following swagger schema specifying format and type for the parameter. I even tried using pattern in the schema but it seems to be not working. May I know how can we limit only path parameters of certain IDs.

```
{
  ......
  "/{pets}/pet": {
      "get": {
          "consumes": [
              "application/json"
          ],
          "produces": [
              "application/json"
          ],
          "parameters": [{
              "name": "pets",
              "in": "path",
              "required": true,
              "schema": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "pattern": "[A-Za-z0-9]{6}"
              }
          }],
          "responses": {
              "200": {
                  "description": "200 response",
                  "schema": {
                      "$ref": "#/definitions/Empty"
                  }
              }
          },
          "x-amazon-apigateway-request-validator": "Validate query string parameters and headers",
          "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
              "responses": {
                  "default": {
                      "statusCode": "200"
                  }
              },
              "requestTemplates": {
                  "application/json": "##  See ...."
              },
              "uri": "........",
              "passthroughBehavior": "when_no_templates",
              "httpMethod": "POST",
              "contentHandling": "CONVERT_TO_TEXT",
              "type": "aws"
          }
      }
  }
  .....
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
https://api.example.com/aacc77/pet -- Accept
https://api.example.com/aacc77s/pet -- Reject
https://api.example.com/aacc7/pet -- Reject
https://api.example.com/aacc_7/pet -- Reject
```

Basically, I want to use this regex pattern for the path **[A-Za-z0-9]{6}**.

```
"pets": {
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "Pets Schema",
  "type": "string",
  "pattern": "[A-Za-z0-9]{6}"
}
```

I see that there is a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36461564/2007486), I wonder whether there is a solution available for this.

Comment: I asked the same on AWS forums also [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=267060), fyi.

Comment: Unfortunately, API Gateway only validate the required request parameters in the URI, query string, and headers of an incoming request are included and non-blank.

Comment: @KaHouIeong This [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/how-to-remove-boilerplate-validation-logic-in-your-rest-apis-with-amazon-api-gateway-request-validation/) states: _"This feature leverages API Gateway models to enable the validation of request payloads against the specified schema, including validation rules as defined in the JSON-Schema Validation specification. Request validators also support basic validation of required HTTP request parameters in the URI, query string, and headers."_