# Unicode characters validation in AWS API Gateway

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, validation, aws-api-gateway

I try to do a name validation in my AWS API Gateway. Everything works fine until I try any UTF-8 characters (like Chinese names for example).

My original property definition in the model was:

`"firstName" : {
      "type" : "string",
      "minLength" : 1,
      "maxLength" : 2147483647,
      "pattern" : "^[ a-zA-Z\\d,.'’\"()/|:®-]*$"
    }`

I tried to change the pattern to support the Perl-compatible `\\p` and the `{L}` for letter, and now its `"^[ \\p{L}\\d,.'’\"()/|:®-]*$"` but it still don't accept any unicode chars.

Is there any way to validate unicode chars in API Gateway?

Comment: What is the regex flavor?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew what do you mean by that?

Comment: What regex library is used there to parse and handle regular expressions?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear: it's in the model in aws api gateway. It uses whatever flavor aws is using

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47194894/validating-request-path-parameter-of-aws-api-gateway, it seems that this validation is just not supported.